# App crashing after running an app on iPhone 12 Pro Max for testing with Xcode 12.5.1 M1 Mac

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-m1

I have been developing an app and running it on different iOS simulators below iOS 14.5 but now when I connect my iPhone which has iOS 14.5 for testing the app. The app crashes and the Xcode throws this error: Note that the error only happen when I try to type a message to another user, since it is a chat application

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidPathValidation', reason: '(child:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

This is only happening with iOS 14.5.
I have re installed the pods etc using
arch -x86_64 sudo gem install cocoapods
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
arch -x86_64 pod repo update
arch -x86_64 pod install

everything is unto date.
Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue. When the conversation ID in Firebase was created it ended with the time stamp. The time stamp on iOS 14.5 using dateformatter is different than in previous releases and it was adding some unwanted strings to the ID thus the app couldn't access the conversation ID and crashed.
changed it like
formattre.dateFormat = "MMM d, y HH:mm:ss E Z"